# How to access an S3 Endpoint with a lambda function and Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

Quick overview, I am building out a cloudformation template which contains:

VPC

IGW

public subnet

private subnet

NATGateway

Route tables

S3 bucket

databases

lambda functions

One of these lambda functions is pulling data from an API and sending it to an S3 bucket. My issues is how do I give this lambda function the permissions to do its job without giving it access to S3 in IAM. But, instead writing a bucket policy which will allow only that lambda function to access S3?

```
  S3:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: "some-random-bucket"

  S3BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    DependsOn: S3
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref S3
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          Action:
            - 's3:PutObject'
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::some-random-bucket/*"
          Principal: 'arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ACCOUNT-NUMBER:function:lambda_function_1'
```

And the S3 Endpoint which I created is as follows:

```
  S3Endpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "s3:PutObject"
            Resource:
              Fn::ImportValue: !Sub S3Id
      ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.s3'
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

I've tried changing the principal in both the S3BucketPolicy and the S3Endpoint. However, I just cannot seem to get the correct permissions to send to S3.

I also, changed the principal in the S3BucketPolicy to '*'

that allowed my lambda function to write to S3. However, I do only want to restrict access to only the lambda function

so '*' ultimately is not going to work for me here.

If I could get some insight on this it would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with your current policies? What errors do you get?

Comment: The errors I get are invalid policy syntax. But, if I use '*' as the principal everything works fine. I just cannot seem to lock it down to the lambda function.

Comment: Have you used `aws:PrincipalArn` as shown in the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html#vpc-endpoints-policies-s3?